# "Permission Denied" error in IE doesn't seem to match the javascript code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Running in IE is a legacy app built with frames that makes alot of references cross-frame like parent.header.blah.blah and parent.sidebar.so.and.so.  Worked fine in old IE compatibility mode.  Works in chrome and edge (chromium).

But in regular IE without compatibility mode on, it's throwing a permission denied error on line 43.  Thing is, it throws the error in the console NO MATTER WHAT IS ON LINE 43!!!  I added superfluous lines of code to push other code down, took out code to move other code up.  Doesn't matter, the console ALWAYS says it's on line 43.

I put breakpoints in and noticed the error doesn't actually add to the console until AFTER the javascript has finished running.  The page is very large with ALOT of javascript, and it's dificult to comment a section out without breaking the page to experiment with what might be causing the permission denied.

Permission Denied is supposed to indicate a same-origin violation as I understand it, but all frames and files are coming through the same servlet on the same URL with only parameters changing.  I printed out the document.domain of every frame, they all are identical.

So..I'm not even sure what to do at this point to narrow it down.  How can I figure out what is really the offending piece of code...or even section?

UPDATE - So it seems that the error is actually coming from a function in another frame being called from this frame (nowhere near line 43 by the way).  That function is managing the options in a select list.  The actual error comes here:

```
for (var k=0; k < assetListz.options.length; k++) {
    if (assetListz.options[k].value == currentAsset) { //permission denied!
        inList = true;
        assetListz.options[k].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

assetListz didn't have a 'z' on it until I just did that to make sure I wasn't accidentally getting scope to some OTHER assetList.  I can test the length of the assetList, but as soon as I check the value on that second line, kaboom.  Ideas?

Update 2 -

I changed the code to get the assetlist in each reference.  No storing it.  Blows up in the same place.

```
for (var k=0; k < document.getElementById('assetList').options.length; k++) {
    if (document.getElementById('assetList').options[k].value == currentAsset) {
        inList = true;
        document.getElementById('assetList').options[k].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code we can only speculate. There are use-cases additionally to CORS issues for Permission denied error. An outdated reference to a DOM element can trigger this error in IE. That is, you're storing a reference (to an element in a iframe) to a variable, and then re-create the element (ex. setting innerHTML), the reference in the variable gets outdated, and is not accessible anymore.

Comment: Rather than being javascript specific this might be IE specific, for example https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-permission-denied-script-error-in-internet-explorer-11-914fe758-b3a8-2fae-dcad-250db1158af9

Comment: @Teemu - The app does get reference to option arrays quite often.  That gives me something to look for.  Which is what i need.  Sorry about not putting the js up, but since the line of the error is lying, I would have to paste hundreds of lines of javascript up...it wouldn't be very helpful.  Finding WHERE the problem lay is my problem.

Comment: IE has always been inaccurate with the linenumbers in error messages, but not that inaccurate. Make sure the page is not cached, and doublecheck the source file from the message, maybe it's pointing to an inline event listener attribute in a html file, where the actual function causing the error was called.

Comment: @Teemu - Your first suggestion lead me to find the information I added in the 'update' section above.  Any further thoughts?

Comment: Try to use debugger and step thru to figure out exactly what's happening

Comment: The cross-frame references gets outdated also if you refresh an iframe (or the main page), but the calling code doesn't update the refrences it uses. I'd assume this would trigger an error in any browser, though.

Comment: @Teemu -  That's just it though, the app GETS the reference to the select in the same method it is used in.  The getElementById() call is about ten lines above what i quoted.  It's not holding the reference.  I can step through and see that the permission denied in the watch...but nothing i do seems to make it go away.  I moved the code into the called frame as a function.  I tried to delay it using a timer so that the timer would run in the frame that owns the select.

Comment: Unfortunately you're in [a similar situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392470/1169519) I was for an year ago. We just can't fix the code we can't see.

Comment: @Teemu - Added code to get the assetlist on demand (see update 2).  Not stored in any var.  Blows up in the exact same sport...when I access the value of the option.  Anyway, you've helped me get to the offending line of code - that value access.  Now I just need to figure out what to DO about it.  You can see there's no simultaneous update.  That's why I still think this is about spanning frames.  But I don't know what to do about it since the error is clearly wrong if it's a same-origin violation because they're all the same origin.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: One more jab into dark, take a look at the Internet Settings of IE, I'd recall there are some options with which you can block the interaction between windows.

Comment: I think the issue might be related with IE settings. You can try to put your sites into Trusted sites list. You can also try to uncheck Enable Enhanced Protected Mode [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIQjv.png) to see if it can fix the issue. Besides, which document mode does IE use when the sites running in compatibility mode?

Comment: @YuZhou - Unfortunately, I can't modify those settings.  It's a government machine and they have policies preventing me from adding trusted sites or from modifying those two settings.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got this fixed.  I'm not sure exactly WHY this fix works, though I can guess.  It seems that by rewriting the method so that it avoids use of the options array on the select object, everything works fine. I reference it just once to get the length...which it allows.  but if i try to get a specific option by assetList.options[i].anything, then I get permission denied.

I still think this is a bug in IE11's same-origin code, but lucky for me, it seems like MS didn't re-use code so the same bug didn't 'protect' all means of accessing the select options.  Just via the array property.  Or maybe something else is goin on.  I just know this worked for me.

```
//By changing the value attribute, we change the current selection.  
assetList.value = currentAsset.toUpperCase();
if(assetList.selectedIndex == -1) {
    //this means the current asset wasn't in the list.
    if(assetList.options.length >= 1000) {
        //not allowed to add more than 1000. And if so, set the selectedIndex back
        alert("The Active Asset List contains the maximum of 1000 entries. \n" +
        "The current Asset ID '" + currentAsset + "' was not added to the Active Asset List.");
        assetList.selectedIndex = currentSelectedIndex;
        return;
    } else {
        var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        option.value = currentAsset;
        option.text = currentAsset;
        assetList.add(option, 0);
        assetList.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```